# Set animator float according to object's horizontal movement speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, velocity, animator

Hey I am currently making a very simple 3D endless runner game and  I am trying to make a animator float increase when the characters speed increases. 
I'm using a very simple code to make the character move:

`void Update () {
       transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*speed)`;

Then i tired to match the animator float like this:

`m_Anim.SetFloat("H_Speed", m_Rigidbody.velocity.z);`

m_Anim is referring to the Animator and the m_Rigidbody is referring to the objects Rigidbody

Comment: Are you expecting `transform.Translate` to change the rigidbodies velocity?

Comment: I would recommend not using `transform.Translate` if you are going to be using Rigidbody's for anything.  You can use `Rigidbody.movePosition` and `Rigidbody.moveRotation` to do basically the same things you would use `transform.Translate` and `transform.Rotate` for.

Comment: Im quite new to coding so Im not that familiar with the language, how would you go with doing this? I just figured that transform.Translate did the job quite smoothly which for an example rigidbody.AddForce did not. When i tried Rigidbody.movePosition it got somewhat glitchy. PS: sorry for my grammar, english is not my native language.

Comment: You should use `movePosition`, and `moveRotation` in a `FixedUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

`Transform.Translate` doesn't affect rigidbody's velocity. It's like teleportation. So if you want to stick to using `Translate` you should set the speed of animation according to `speed` from this line:

`transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*speed);`

Comment: I night just be stupid But i tried to do this: m_Anim.SetFloat(«H_Speed», speed); Is that an okay solution for a bad code or?

Comment: You also may want to multiply the `speed` variable here by some coefficient if your animation is playing too fast or too slow with this method.

Comment: I did this: transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*speed/4); should i rather multiply the animation or is it the same?

Comment: Basically it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a reputation to add a comment for clarification for your problem (for example why do you need to set a float in the Animator?) but here is my reply. speed in your Translate will be a fixed speed so will always stays the same unless you have a code changing it. For example increasing it when up arrow is pressed and down when down arrow is pressed.

```
void Update () {
   transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime);
   m_Anim.SetFloat("H_Speed", speed);
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){ 
       speed++;}
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){ 
       speed--;}
}
```